# How to show ads in a react native app

Tags: facebook, react-native, admob, ads

There are some react native components for ads but some of them don't work with current versions of react native. (react-native-admob for example).  There is a serious lack of information about showing ads in react native and I can't seem to figure out how most people accomplish this.  Does everyone really write their own native UI component to accomplish this? Is react-native-admob really the only way to use admob currently?  Am I just completely missing some simple way to do this?

Comment: try this - https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob and this https://github.com/melihmucuk/react-native-admob-sample . Most of other advertisement platforms will work as long as you have wrapper above them.. I'm sure there will be samples provided by those adnetworks

Comment: Like I said, react-native-admob doesn't work with the current version of react native.  The other repo, react-native-admob-sample is over a year old and uses a very old version of react native.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin and https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova:

```
$ npm install react-native-cordova-plugin --save
$ node_modules/.bin/cordova-plugin add cordova-plugin-camera cordova-admob
```

In **android/settings.gradle**:

```
 include ':app'
+ include ':cordovaplugin'
+ project(':cordovaplugin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-cordova-plugin/framework/android')
```

In **android/app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules    ...
+   compile project(':cordovaplugin')
}
```

In **android/app/src/main/java/com/appname/MainActivity.java**

```
...
+  import io.cordova.reactnative.CordovaPluginPackage;
...
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
     ...
     @Override
     protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
         return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                 new MainReactPackage(),
+                cordovaPluginPackage = new CordovaPluginPackage(this)
         );
     }
+    private CordovaPluginPackage cordovaPluginPackage;
+    @Override
+    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
+        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
+        cordovaPluginPackage.setSavedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
+    }
+    @Override
+    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
+        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
+        cordovaPluginPackage.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
+    }
}
```

In either **index.android.js** or any other component:

```
var Cordova = require('react-native-cordova-plugin');
Cordova.navigator.admob.createBannerView({publisherId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB"});
Cordova.addEventListener(Cordova.navigator.admob.events.onAdLoaded, onEvent);
```

Comment: The cordova plugin is stuck on RN 0.29

Answer (score 0):

react-native-admob was a pain to set up. I was beginning to wonder myself if it was broken. But it isn't, you just need to set up a few things. Set up for Android was my biggest issue, but I found this walkthrough guide to help:

https://pradnyachoudhari.wordpress.com/2019/03/22/integrating-google-admob-in-react-native-android-project/

There are also walkthroughs for IOS.

I followed it and it worked for me, although you won't need to add package to MainApplication.java, just import it and you are good.

Hope this helps!